# Optimal way to retry a JDBC connection:

Tags: java, exception, javafx, jdbc, service

I have a remote database that I access through JDBC. Network is pretty poor this side so I get a couple of network related `SQLException`s when I'm sometimes working with the application.
I've decided to retry the connection thrice if it failed (spacing it out with 2 seconds). I see there are different ways to do it but I'm wondering if the way I went about it was okay.

Secondly, since I use background services to access the database, do I need to be calling `service.restart()` if the connection could not be made? Or is just retrying the connection alone just fine as per my implementation below:

```
public class Sample {
    public Sample() {
        DatabaseService databaseService = new DatabaseService();
        databaseService.start();
        databaseService.setOnFailed(event->{
            //do I do retries here? databaseService.restart();
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Sample();
    }

    private class Person {
        private String name;


        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

    private class DatabaseService extends Service<Person> {
        @Override
        protected Task<Person> createTask() {
            return new GetPersonTask();
        }

        private class GetPersonTask extends Task<Person> {
            @Override
            protected Person call() throws Exception {
                Connection db = DatabaseConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
                //retrieve from database
                return new Person("Sample");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class DatabaseConnection {
    private Connection connection;
    private static DatabaseConnection instance;

    private DatabaseConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:mariadb://host.com/database";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "";
            int count = 0;
            int maxTries = 3;
            //3 retries in establishing connection
            while (true) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    System.out.println("INFO: Attempting remote connection to host.com");
                }
                try {
                    this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            url,
                            username,
                            password
                    );
                    break;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("ERR: Connection not established - Retrying ");
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    if (++count == maxTries) throw e;
                }
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public static DatabaseConnection getInstance() throws SQLException {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseConnection();
        } else if (instance.getConnection().isClosed()) {
            instance = new DatabaseConnection();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

I've changed my Singleton Class to use a pooling connection with `Hikari` instead:

```
public class DatabaseConnection {
    private static HikariDataSource ds;

    static {
        ds = new HikariDataSource();
        String url = "jdbc:mariadb://host.com/database";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "";
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        ds.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setJdbcUrl(url);
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("user", username);
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);
        ds.setAutoCommit(false);
    }

    private DatabaseConnection() {
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return ds.getConnection();
    }

}
```

Comment: **It is naive to open a database on the Internet!** Otherwise, it is desirable to use a pool whose connections to reuse.

Comment: Please explain how I could? Do I just simply follow [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/) Also. Does the pool handle automatic retries (if the initial connection can't be made)?

Comment: Check this out https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Comment: @mrmcwolf May you give it just one last glance through? I've made an edit with my code. I'm using `Hikari` since that's the one MariaDB uses on their website. Replaced the `Singleton` class with that instead. Since everything works under the hood, I just call `DatabaseConnection.getConnection()` whenever I want to use it and it should work normally and mitigate those network exceptions? Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Also set a test query (`HikariConfig::setConnectionTestQuery()`) for example `select 1` to make the pool validate the connections before using them. That way, there should be no problems, at least with resources. But remember that opening a database directly on the Internet is a bad idea.

Comment: My apologies but I still don't understand what you mean by "opening" , please dumb it down even further for me. Is there a different implementation I should use?

Comment: So, you use the database directly over the Internet, relying on a username and password for protection. This is an architecture that is chosen for projects that use a private network or VPN. If you are going to use a public network (Internet) to access the database, it is desirable to use an intermediate server - facade, which provides an API for access to the database itself. This is true even on a private network where you want to ensure that users can't break business rules for data access.

Comment: So I'm using a cPanel based server. You can set IP addresses that are allowed to access the database. Is that not enough? Which service do you recommend I checkout?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "enough". A specific host may be sitting behind an IP address, but a network of thousands of hosts may also be sitting. Also, if the application uses a mobile network and / or is on a mobile device (phone,laptop) the firewall will not work (because you will change the address from which calls are constantly sent). You also need to keep in mind what kind of people use your application - I guess you notice that you have set a hard name and password to access the SQL server in your application. In general, the topic of security is complex and often project-specific.

Comment: The application is only meant to run on their static IP address. But yeah I see the caveats of it. I'm reading more into it

Comment: Second that for for `Hikrari` -- small and fast library to pool db connections

Comment: @trilogy implementation looking okay?